# I am getting synxtax error for creating stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_00.ROWPERROW;

DELIMITER $$
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_00.ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_00.test_deposit_first INTO n;
  DECLARE a, b BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE c TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED; 
  DECLARE d DECIMAL(20,8);
  DECLARE e,f INT(10) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE g TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT dno,uid,dptype,amount,created,updated,status FROM test_00.test_deposit_first;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;

  REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
    IF NOT done THEN
        insert into test_00.test_deposit_third(dno,uid,dptype,amount,created,updated,status) VALUES(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
    END IF;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;
   
    CLOSE cur1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting error:

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE a, b BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE c TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE ' at line 7
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE a, b BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE c TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE ' at line 7
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE a, b BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE c TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE ' at line 7

please help me :o

Comment: You cannot select in the middle of a declare block..Format of stored programs is declaraions..code

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you, you are right, it's fixed now!

Comment: @P.Salmon You should reply in answer question section, i can mark it as the answer. It gives u reputation as well.